# VSCode How to fold/unfold all sub regions

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Fairly new in macos and wondering how to perform the key combination for Fold/Unfold all subregions in macos.

According to the documentation the key combination is
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf:

`⌘K ⌘[` to fold

`⌘K ⌘]` to unfold

Problem is VSCode is registering the input as:

`⌘K ⌥⌘8` and `⌘K ⌥⌘9`

In my understanding `⌥8` is a `[` and `⌥9` ia a `]` so how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Toggle fold is a good workaround `⌘K ⌘L`